# I'm trying to mutate bytes coming from a stream because decoding, but it's not working

Tags: arrays, go, streamreader

I'm trying to wrap an `io.ReaderCloser`, which in production would come from a request handler, with a custom reader that can be passed into a JSON decoder.

I created the below

```
import (
    "io"
)

// RemoveNull is a stream wrapper that should remove null bytes from the byte stream
type RemoveNull struct {
    Reader io.ReadCloser
}

// NewRemoveNullStream creates a new RemoveNull reader which passes the stream through a null check first
func NewRemoveNullStream(reader io.ReadCloser) RemoveNull {
    return RemoveNull{
        Reader: reader,
    }
}

// Read wraps a Reader to remove null bytes in the stream
func (null RemoveNull) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = null.Reader.Read(p)
    if err != nil {
        return n, err
    }

    nn := 0
    for i := range p {
        if p[i] != 0 {
            p[nn] = p[i]
            nn++

        }
    }
    p = p[:nn]
    // fmt.Println(p) i can see the value of p changing and all the null bytes are removed
    return n, nil
}

// Close closes the internal reader
func (null RemoveNull) Close() error {
    return null.Close()
}
```

When I run the following I can see from the print statement that indeed all the null bytes are removed and the len(p) == the size of all the expected good bytes. I wrote the test below to see if the code if working as I intended, and that's where I realized it's not.

Here is the full test

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "testing"

    "github.com/francoispqt/gojay" // can be replaced with the std json lib, code still doesn't work
)

func TestRemoveNull_Read(t *testing.T) {
    type fields struct {
        Reader io.ReadCloser
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name   string
        fields fields
        want   string
    }{
        {
            name: "should remove null bytes",
            fields: fields{
                Reader: ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader([]byte{123, 34, 98, 111, 100, 121, 34, 58, 34, 102, 101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 109, 97, 108, 101, 34, 125})),
            },
            want: "female",
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            reader := tt.fields.Reader
            reader = NewRemoveNullStream(tt.fields.Reader) // wrapper the reader above in the nullByte reader

            // passed the reader into this JSON unmarshaller
            decoder := gojay.BorrowDecoder(reader)
            defer decoder.Release()

            var v _testStruct
            err := decoder.DecodeObject(&v)
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatalf("ReadAll failed %v", err)
            }

            bb, _ := json.Marshal(v)
            fmt.Println(string(bb)) // all the null bytes are still present

            fmt.Println(len(v.Body), len(tt.want))
            if v.Body != tt.want {
                t.Fatalf("DecodeObject() unexpected value, got %s want %s", v.Body, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}

type _testStruct struct {
    Body string `json:"body"`
}

func (v *_testStruct) UnmarshalJSONObject(dec *gojay.Decoder, k string) error {

    switch k {
    case "body":
        err := dec.String(&v.Body)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

// NKeys returns the number of keys to unmarshal
func (v *_testStruct) NKeys() int { return 0 }
```

From the test I can see that all the null bytes are still present when decoding, yet in the RemoveNull reader I can see that all the null bytes have been removed from the underline array. Any thoughts on whats wrong and how i can achieve the goal of removing the bytes from the stream to avoid having the decoder decode the null bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are errors in your Read implementation. It terminates prematurely in case of io.EOF, where there is both error and data. It returns the wrong number of bytes read. The last part where you assign the slice is also meaningless as it doesn't update the slice passed into the function.

Try this:

```
func (null RemoveNull) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = null.Reader.Read(p)
    nn := 0
    for i:=0;i<n;i++ {
        if p[i] != 0 {
            p[nn] = p[i]
            nn++

        }
    }
    return nn, err
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver thank you! I was banging my head for hours.